# WPF,s DataGrid insert object as text

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a simple data grid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="SmartTable"></DataGrid>
```

Next, I initialized the columns in the code and bind it to this struct:

```
public struct HddData
{
    public Ellipse status { set; get; }
    public string id { set; get; }
    public string atribute { set; get; }
    public string current { set; get; }
    public string worst { set; get; }
    public string treshhold { set; get; }
    public string data { set; get; }
}
```

And finaly, I'm trying to insert rows in table using foreach:

```
 Ellipse good = new Ellipse();
 Ellipse bad = new Ellipse();
 good.Fill = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF64DD17"));
 bad.Fill = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFD50000"));
 SmartTable.Items.Add(new HddData
 {
     status = attr.Value.IsOK ? good : bad,
     id = attr.Value.id,
     atribute = attr.Value.Attribute,
     current = attr.Value.Current.ToString(),
     worst = attr.Value.Worst.ToString(),
     treshhold = attr.Value.Threshold.ToString(),
     data = attr.Value.Data.ToString("X"),
 });
```

Text data binds fine, but Ellipses is the type of string in cell, shows this:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse
```

How can I display them not as text, but as an ellipse?

Comment: Learn XAML, this stuff is a dead end. You want a DataGridTemplateColumn

Comment: @EdPlunkett: +1. majukin: You need to do some templating of your datagrid columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind the `Fill` property of an `Ellipse` to an `Ellipse`. Try to use a `ContentControl` in the `CellTemplate`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="test">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding status}"
                                Width="30" Height="30"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public struct HddData
{
    public Brush status { set; get; }
    public string id { set; get; }
    public string atribute { set; get; }
    public string current { set; get; }
    public string worst { set; get; }
    public string treshhold { set; get; }
    public string data { set; get; }
}

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Ellipse Fill="{Binding status}" Width="10" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>                                
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

you need a `Brush` and fill the Ellipse.

Comment: Seems like the truth, but now I got string hex color in the cells :)

Comment: what is that `StackPanel` for ?

Comment: `StackPanel` can contains other controls like `textbox`, `label` etc. so you can add another controls next to `Ellipse`.